# paperclip problem after adding Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1959:in `method_missing': undefined method `class_attribute' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.14/lib/paperclip.rb:182:in `included'
    from /home/prabhu/Desktop/test/vendor/plugins/thoughtbot-paperclip-13d51e3/lib/paperclip/railtie.rb:20:in `include'
    from /home/prabhu/Desktop/test/vendor/plugins/thoughtbot-paperclip-13d51e3/lib/paperclip/railtie.rb:20:in `send'
    from /home/prabhu/Desktop/test/vendor/plugins/thoughtbot-paperclip-13d51e3/lib/paperclip/railtie.rb:20:in `insert'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.14/rails/init.rb:2:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/prabhu/Desktop/test/config/environment.rb:9
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Comment: Do you expect us to actually be able to read this? Kindly reformat to something that's legible. The editor has plenty of tools to help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't asked a question, but I suppose you have some problem with 'class_attribute' being undefined.

I am not sure (too lazy to check ;-), but it's possible that 'class_attribute' has been added in Rails 3. You have Rails 2 and a paperclip gem.

You may try to use an older version of this gem - just check which one is compatible with Rails 2.

UPDATE:

As you can read in the comment, David found you a version of Rails which has this method defined. So, you have two options: upgrade Rails to at least 2.3.9, or downgrade paperclip.

Comment: You're correct : `class_attribute` was originally added to Rails 3. However, it's been backported to Rails 2.3.9 so that might be an option for OP.

Comment: that problem solved now i am getting following error while getting trying upload image         [paperclip] /usr/bin/identify '-format %wx%h :file' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/stream20110715-11730-kimtac-0.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
[paperclip] /usr/bin/identify '-format %wx%h :file' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/stream20110715-11730-kimtac-0.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>